# How to import Mathematica folders into Workbench

Tags: workbench

I have been working with *Mathematica* for a while and have accumulated a number of folders (not in *Workbench* project form), each with a few files such as a .nb file, maybe a .m file, and their products (images etc.).

I then acquired *Wolfram Workbench*, and am up and running, and wish to transfer my existing folders to *Workbench*. If I try

```
File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Next
```

and select the directory that contains my folders, the information up the top of the dialogue box says, "No projects are found to import".

If I simply transfer my folders to the base *Workbench* directory, they are not visible in the Package Explorer or Navigator even after pressing F5 (Refresh).

Any ideas?

---

PS $\hspace{5mm}$ After experimenting a little more, I've discovered that I can go

```
File -> New -> Project -> Mathematica -> Basic Project
```

and create a project with the same name as the folder I wish to import; then paste the contents of my folder into the project folder. This is a work-around, but what I'd really like to do is import all of my existing folders into the base workspace and have *Workbench* recognise them as projects (and create the necessary infrastructure around them if need be), without my having to faff around creating projects manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Workbench (and Eclipse in general) recognizes a directory as a project, if it contains special [project description file](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fproject_description_file.html).

I don't know any "batch project creation" functionality in Workbench, but you can easily programmatically add necessary files to your folders with Mathematica.

Description file for Mathematica projects looks like this:

```
template = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<projectDescription>
\t<name>`1`</name>
\t<comment></comment>
\t<projects>
\t</projects>
\t<buildSpec>
\t\t<buildCommand>
\t\t\t<name>com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.MathematicaProjectBuilder</name>
\t\t\t<arguments>
\t\t\t</arguments>
\t\t</buildCommand>
\t</buildSpec>
\t<natures>
\t\t<nature>com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.SimpleMathematicaNature</nature>
\t</natures>
</projectDescription>
";
```

where `` `1` `` is a placeholder for project name.

Take all relevant directory paths:

```
directories = 
    Select[
        FileNames["/path/to/root/directory/*"],
        FileType[#] === Directory &
    ]
```

and create description files with project names same as directory names:

```
Export[
    FileNameJoin[{#, ".project"}], 
    ToString[StringForm[template, FileNameTake[#]], StandardForm], 
    "String"
] & /@ directories
```

Now you should be able to import "Existing Projects into Workspace".